# Java application run from task scheduler stops working every second hour

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Currently there is no way i can set up the the java application as a Windows Service, so i have a Task scheduler set up, with the following settings.

**General** - *Run whether user is logged in or not*

**Triggers** - *Run once at X time, repeat every 1 hour indefinitely*. *Enabled* is checked.

**Actions** - *Start a program* - path to the run.bat that runs the java application.

**Conditions** - default (*Start the task only if the computer is on AC powe*r and *Stop if the computer switches to battery power*)

**Settings** - *Allow task to be run on demand* and *If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop* are checked, and *Stop the Task if it runs longer than* is set to *2 hours*.

While inspecting logs, it seems that the application is working fine and is getting restarted, until at some point some days later, it stops working at 13:00:00 and starts working at 14:00:00 and stops working at 15:00:00 and then again starts working at 16:00:00 etc. etc.

EDIT: Added log

> 10:00:01.628 [Thread-542] TRACE Job: .. | 2320041 | Event: RunOutOfData
>
> 10:00:01.628 [Thread-542] INFO  Job: .. | Going to sleep for 30.0
> seconds.
>
> 11:00:04.607 [main] INFO  Program: Service started.
>
> 11:00:04.623 [main] INFO  Program: Going to use Azure storage.
>
> 11:00:04.623 [main] INFO  Program: (Re)starting download operations
> from service.
>
> 11:00:04.623 [main] TRACE: Requesting bearer token from
> microsoft.

Above log shows that it went to sleep for 30 seconds, and then it magically starts up after a hour. Usually what follows after the sleep log is this line

> 09:59:59.018 [Thread-543] INFO  Job: .. | Back in business!

And yes, logging level is verbose, and if there was any error, it would be logged here.

EDIT 2:
[Here is the last setting i didn't mention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpAN0.png) This might be the root cause.

Comment: increase your logging level to get more info on what really happened.

Comment: The thing is, logging set to verbose.

Comment: you need to include some kind of proof to show that it didn't work at 15:00. For example, a piece of your log file. Your setup looks fine. Without proof, the question we need to ask you is, how can you be sure that it did not run at 15:00? maybe it did run, but just didn't produce the expected result, encountered error/exception or something.

Comment: @SparedWhisle I have added some proof of my claim. Hope that helps